# Converting class components to hooks form in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Not sure how I would convert this class component to hooks form. I tried to, but the app doesn't run the same.
Here's the original code written as class components-

```
  class Area extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: [],
    tooltipX: null,
    tooltipY: null,
    tooltipIndex: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.reorderData();
  }

  reorderData = () => {
    const reorderedData = DATA.sort((a, b) => {
      // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
      // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
      return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: reorderedData,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, tooltipX, tooltipY, tooltipIndex } = this.state;
    const contentInset = { left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 7 };

    const ChartPoints = ({ x, y, color }) =>
      data.map((item, index) => (
        <Circle
          key={index}
          cx={x(moment(item.date))}
          cy={y(item.score)}
          r={6}
          stroke={color}
          fill="white"
          onPress={() =>
            this.setState({
              tooltipX: moment(item.date),
              tooltipY: item.score,
              tooltipIndex: index,
            })
          }
        />
      ));

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {data.length !== 0 ? (
            <AreaChart
              style={{ height: '70%' }}
              data={data}
              yAccessor={({ item }) => item.score}
              xAccessor={({ item }) => moment(item.date)}
              contentInset={contentInset}
              svg={{ fill: '#003F5A' }}
              numberOfTicks={10}
              yMin={0}
              yMax={10}
            >
              <Grid svg={{ stroke: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.09)' }} belowChart={false} />
              <ChartPoints color="#003F5A" />
              <Tooltip
                tooltipX={tooltipX}
                tooltipY={tooltipY}
                color="#003F5A"
                index={tooltipIndex}
                dataLength={data.length}
              />
            </AreaChart>
          ) : (
            <View
              style={{
                height: '50%',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#ccc',
                }}
              >
                There are no responses for this month.
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Tooltip Area Chart</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

This code is being used to integrate tooltip in react native charts. I want to include this code with rest of the project code written in hooks form.

Comment: show us what did you try.

Comment: Please update your question to be more concise. Show us what you have already tried. And if you could highlight or just display the parts that confuse you the most, the question would be much easier to answer.

Comment: don't remove your functional component attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
  export default class myPureComponent extends React.PureComponent
```

is equal to:

```
export default React.memo(()=>{
   return <View>//...</view>
},(prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.x === nextProps.x;
  // the component will be updated only on `x` prop changes.
})
```

`componentDidMount` is equal to:

`React.useEffect(()=>reorderData(),[]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your codes properly.

Add a [] in your use effects to it only render once.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      reorderData();
    },[]);   //add [] as a dependency, this renders useEffect only on mount.
```

Full codes

```
const Area = () => {
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
const [ tooltipX, setTooltipX ] = useState(null);
const [ tooltipY, setTooltipY ] = useState(null);
const [ tooltipIndex, setTooltipIndex ] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => reorderData(),[]);

const reorderData = () => {
    const reorderedData = DATA.sort((a, b) => {
      // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
      // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
      return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });
    
    setData(reorderedData);
  };

 const contentInset = { left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 7 };
 
 const ChartPoints = ({ x, y, color }) =>
      data.map((item, index) => (
        <Circle
          key={index}
          cx={x(moment(item.date))}
          cy={y(item.score)}
          r={6}
          stroke={color}
          fill="white"
          onPress={() =>
            this.setState({
              tooltipX: moment(item.date),
              tooltipY: item.score,
              tooltipIndex: index,
            })
          }
        />
      ));

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {data.length !== 0 ? (
            <AreaChart
              style={{ height: '70%' }}
              data={data}
              yAccessor={({ item }) => item.score}
              xAccessor={({ item }) => moment(item.date)}
              contentInset={contentInset}
              svg={{ fill: '#003F5A' }}
              numberOfTicks={10}
              yMin={0}
              yMax={10}
            >
              <Grid svg={{ stroke: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.09)' }} belowChart={false} />
              <ChartPoints color="#003F5A" />
              <Tooltip
                tooltipX={tooltipX}
                tooltipY={tooltipY}
                color="#003F5A"
                index={tooltipIndex}
                dataLength={data.length}
              />
            </AreaChart>
          ) : (
            <View
              style={{
                height: '50%',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#ccc',
                }}
              >
                There are no responses for this month.
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Tooltip Area Chart</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  
}
```